# How to resolve "There are no recommendations available at the moment" task list error in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I am using Sharepoint 2013, In this I am facing issues the tasks list showing below error.

There was an exception in the Database. Please retry your operation and if the problem presists, contact an administrator.
Correlation ID: 979a259e-9143-3083-19ea-47e187623f55

Is their any ideas for this?

Comment: are you using SharePoint online or SharePoint server 2013? if you are using sharepoint 2013 on-premise, check ULS log file based on the Correlation ID to find more information.